# I need the results from these two queries to be combined into one statement

Tags: sql, many-to-many

The set up is a contact table, employee table, and an Employee_contact table with a many to many relationship. I want to know how to combine these two queries into one for a combined result set.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, (ContactNumber) AS Home  
FROM Employees AS E
JOIN Employees_Contacts AS EC ON E.EmployeeID = EC.EmployeeID
JOIN Contacts AS C on EC.ContactID = C.ContactID
WHERE ContactType = 'Home Phone'

SELECT FirstName, LastName, (ContactNumber) AS Fax
FROM Employees AS E
JOIN Employees_Contacts AS EC ON E.EmployeeID = EC.EmployeeID
JOIN Contacts AS C on EC.ContactID = C.ContactID
WHERE ContactType = 'Home Fax';
```

Comment: Is there at most one home number and one home fax number for any given customer?

Comment: At most? Are you asking if there can only be one of each type? The Contacts table is set up with the columns; ContactId, ContactNumber, ContactType. I would say no, you could potentially put two home numbers for one employee in the table so long as they have a unique ContactId. Though I would prefer to add a new contact type for this situation such as Home Phone 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName,
   MAX(CASE WHEN ContactType = 'Home Phone' THEN ContactNumber END) AS Home,
   MAX(CASE WHEN ContactType = 'Home Fax' THEN ContactNumber END) AS Fax
FROM Employees AS E
    JOIN Employees_Contacts AS EC ON E.EmployeeID = EC.EmployeeID
    JOIN Contacts AS C on EC.ContactID = C.ContactID
WHERE ContactType IN ('Home Phone','Home Fax')
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

Comment: This worked out best! Thanks! I'm still learning all of this and I guess I'm just curious, but I was wondering if there are other ways of doing this?

Comment: @JordannSeward -- To get the home and fax numbers on the same line as the names, this is my preferred method.  However, you can also use multiple correlated subqueries to return the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Using Case Statement

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, 
    CASE
        WHEN ContactType = 'Home Phone' then ContactNumber
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Home,
    CASE
        WHEN ContactType = 'Home Fax' then ContactNumber
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Fax
FROM Employees AS E
JOIN Employees_Contacts AS EC ON E.EmployeeID = EC.EmployeeID
JOIN Contacts AS C on EC.ContactID = C.ContactID
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what kind of result do you expect. This one returns all Employees with first HomePhone and HomeFax if any:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName,
   (select top 1 ContactNumber from Employees_Contacts AS EC 
                JOIN Contacts AS C on EC.ContactID = C.ContactID 
                where E.EmployeeID = EC.EmployeeID 
                and EC.ContactType = 'Home Phone') as HomePhone,
   (select top 1 ContactNumber from Employees_Contacts AS EC
                JOIN Contacts AS C on EC.ContactID = C.ContactID 
                where E.EmployeeID = EC.EmployeeID 
                and EC.ContactType = 'Home Fax') as Fax
FROM Employees AS E
```

Your query was returning all Phones and Faxes.